# How to change a cell contents to a value and back in tabulator

Tags: javascript, tabulator

So I am building a table that holds MITRE ATTCK data (https://attack.mitre.org/)
The table is building using public data from sandboxes that detonates malware and classifies some of this actions to specific technique listed under these mitre attck.

What i want to show is the ATTCK as it is, and when you click on a cell (indicating any technique like "Exploiting Public Facing Application" that cell would change to another value (indicating top industry targeted for instance, or how to mitigate).

I am thinking that i would have an array or arrays like `["Account Discovery", "Canada"]`, and then when clicked the value of the cell would change from "Account Discovery" to "Canada".

I was looking at tabulator History Callbacks and `cellEdit` might look like the way to go but i am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to change the value of a cell on a user click you can use the ***cellClick*** callback in the column definition and the ***setValue*** function on the [Cell Component](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/components#component-cell) passed into that function.

The example below will iterate through the list of possible values on each click

```js
{title:"Name", field:"name", cellClick:function(e, cell){
    //e - the click event object
    //cell - cell component

    //define list of possible values
    var values = ["Account Discovery", "Canada"];
    
    //find index of current value and shift to next value
    var index = values.indexOf(cell.getValue()); 
    index ++;

    if(index >= values.length){
       index = 0;
    }
    
    //set cell to new value
    cell.setValue(values[index]); 
}},
```